# Some doubts about Java SWING and Swing Application Framework

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swing-app-framework

I have this simple Main class that use swing to show an Hello World label but I have some doubt about this code because this is my first time that I create GUI in Java:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

public class Main extends SingleFrameApplication {

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        show(new JLabel("Hello World"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main a = new Main();
        a.startup();
    }

}
```

My doubts are:

1. From what I have understand the **JLabel()** method is a pure **Swing** method that simply create a textual label showing the Hello World message. This code use also the **startup() method that, from what I have understand, is a method of the **SingleFrameApplication** class that belong to the so called **Swing Application Framework** ...but...what exactly is this **Swing Application Framework** ? Is it a separate project from Swing? What give me?
2. When I run the application as a classic Java application the Hello World message is show but also appear to me the following error message in the Eclipse console:

> set 23, 2013 12:35:37 PM org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager
>   getApplicationResourceMap Avvertenza: getApplicationResourceMap(): no
>   Application class set 23, 2013 12:35:38 PM
>   org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication initRootPaneContainer
>   Avvertenza: couldn't restore session [mainFrame.session.xml]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage.getApplicationId(LocalStorage.java:254)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage.getDirectory(LocalStorage.java:274)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage$LocalFileIO.getFile(LocalStorage.java:450)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage$LocalFileIO.openInputFile(LocalStorage.java:417)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage.openInputFile(LocalStorage.java:68)
>     at org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage.load(LocalStorage.java:188)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.application.SessionStorage.restore(SessionStorage.java:381)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication.initRootPaneContainer(SingleFrameApplication.java:210)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication.show(SingleFrameApplication.java:268)
>     at Main.startup(Main.java:11)   at Main.main(Main.java:19)

Why? What it exactly means?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: you would ne need something extends JFrame, there you can to place JLabel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create and show a window with a Hello World label, you need to do the following at the minimum:

- Instantiate a JFrame ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)).
- Add your JLabel to it.
- Show the frame.

The oracle tutorial on how to make frames ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)) shows you exactly how to do that.  For easy reference, I copied the specific excerpt that defines/shows your window from there.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//Display the window.
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're extending `SingleFrameApplication`, which is a framework class that performs UI setup and initialization for you, but you're not providing any of the necessary configuration information to it.